# Unable to disconnect a Storage Spaces virtual disk

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

I have a Windows 10 machine running Storage Spaces on 8x2TB drives pool. In that pool, I have created a space (virtual disk) using parity protection. It has been running for some time. Today, I have noticed one of my drives is reporting few `Interface CRC Error Count` occurrences, which usually indicates bad SATA cable. Admittedly, the cable is from AliExpress. I want to take the virtual disk offline using `Disconnect-VirtualDisk` cmdlet in PowerShell. I have executed command `Disconnect-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName PARITY1` in PowerShell with an error, that I can't understand. The PowerShell has been launched As Administrator, so privileges should not be an issue.

Why can't I execute this command?

[image: PowerShell window showing error while executing the command]